# How would you go about creating a favourites list under a users profile?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have just created a login for my website. I am now building a profile page with php and html. Im looking to create a website that has several items in the products page but would also like to enable each user who is logged in to be able to favorite items or add to a list which would then be displayed under their profile page. I'm not sure how to do any of that and was wondering where I would start in creating that list. I would appreciate some guidance on this.

Comment: What storage mechanism are you using? Database?

Comment: for database im using phpadmin

Answer (score -1):

Start by designing your database. User favorites are typical `many-to-many` relationship, so a table with `user_id` and `product_id` would work. You can then display particular user's favorites easily by reading from that table and joining your `products` table.